# Deserialize reqwest query error rustc(E0308)

Tags: rust

Not sure why is this happening, here's a snippet:

**struct:**

```rs
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Snapshot<'a> {
    id              : u32,
    some_data       : &'a str
}

impl<'a> SomeStruct{
    async fn snapshot(url: &str) -> Result<Snapshot<'a>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        let resp = reqwest::get(&url).await?;
        
        let snapshot = resp.json::<Snapshot>().await?;

        println!("{:?}", resp);
        Ok(snapshot)
    }
}
```

**error message:** on the json line

```rs
mismatched types

one type is more general than the other

note: expected trait `models::requests::_::_serde::Deserialize<'de>`
         found trait `models::requests::_::_serde::Deserialize<'_>`rustc(E0308)
```

I imagine this has something to do with the lifecycle of the elements on struct snapshot, but I'm not sure how to properly fix it.

**Cargo.toml**:

```
[dependencies]
actix-web = "3"
reqwest = { version = "0.11.6", features = ["json"] }
async-trait = "0.1.51"
serde = "1.0.130"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concrete problem is that

```rust
resp.json::<Snapshot>()
```

elides the lifetime on `Snapshot`, so you won't be deserializing to `Snapshot<'a>`.

But even if you fix that, this cannot work: Your deserialized `snapshot` does not have anywhere it could borrow its `&'a str from`. The only possibility is `resp`, which is dropped at the end of the `snapshot` function, so you can't return the deserialized `snapshot`. Without more knowledge about the surrounding code, I'd recommend you to change the `&'a str` into a `String`.

---

Addition:

I thought: Hey, so if deserializing would borrow from `resp`, we could just make `resp` live longer:

```rust
struct SomeStruct {
    resp: reqwest::Response,
}
impl SomeStruct {
    async fn new(url: &str) -> anyhow::Result<Self> {
        Ok(Self {
            resp: reqwest::get(url).await?,
        })
    }
    async fn snapshot<'a>(&'a self) -> anyhow::Result<Snapshot<'a>> {
        Ok(self.resp.json::<Snapshot<'a>>().await?)
    }
}
```

but no, that doesn't work. reqwest simply doesn't allow this kind of code:

```
pub async fn json<T: DeserializeOwned>(self) -> Result<T>
```

(`DeserializeOwned` says that `T` must be deserializable for any, arbitrary short lifetime of the callees picking.)

What you can do, however, is to not store `resp`, but its body.

```rust
struct SomeStruct {
    data: bytes::Bytes,
}
impl SomeStruct {
    async fn new(url: &str) -> anyhow::Result<Self> {
        Ok(Self {
            data: reqwest::get(url).await?.bytes().await?,
        })
    }
    async fn snapshot(&self) -> anyhow::Result<Snapshot<'_>> {
        Ok(serde_json::from_slice(&*self.data)?)
    }
}
```

I doubt this is advantageous for performance.

(Semi-related: I always worry about service denial attacks with this kind of code. What if somebody sends GBs of body?)

Comment: that's a good answer. I'm gonna focus now on functionality, and in the future I'll come back for performance.